# Read JSON format out of webpage in SWIFT 3

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to fetch data out of a JSON file on my webserver. In previous versions of SWIFT this worked out:

```
self.url = "https://www.example.com/example"
let requestURL: URL = URL(string: self.url)!
let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL)
let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {
    (data, response, error) -> Void in

    let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
    let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

    if (statusCode == 200) {

        do{

            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments) as? [[String: AnyObject]]

            if let stations = json["ticket"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

                for station in stations! {

                    if let status = station["status"] as? String {
                        self.resultStatus = status

                        if let name = station["name"] as? String {
                            self.clientName = name

                            if let type = station["type"] as? String {
                                self.ticketType = type
                                self.setThemeResult()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        } catch {
            print("Error with Json: \(error)")
        }

    }
}
task.resume()
```

*Well... I know that it's probably a bit messy, but it did work. :)* In SWIFT 3, xcode made some changes to the code.
**This**:

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments) as? [[String: AnyObject]]
```

**Became**:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String: AnyObject]]
```

But now, this error appears.
[image: this]

And I't would be amazing if someone can explain what it means, and maybe come up with a solution.

Thanks in advance.

PS:
I'm aware that there are some questions on this forum that could possibly contain the answer for my problem already. I'm just too new to programming in SWIFT that I have to ask a question about my particular case to find the answer.

Comment: In the latest beta 6 `AnyObject` has been changed to `Any`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your response is `Dictionary` not `Array`, so you need to write `[String: Any]` instead of `[[String: Any]]`

```
 let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
 if let stations = json["ticket"] as? [[String: Any]] {

 }
```

**Note:** If your response is Array than try access first object of array to get dictionary.

```
 if let stations = json[0]["ticket"] as? [[String: Any]] {

 }
```

Comment: If possible show your response of API that will give more idea.

Comment: Thnx! I replaced [[String: AnyObject]] with [String: AnyObject] and it worked again. In a comment @vidian said that 'AnyObject' should be 'Any'. So.. I should use [String: Any]?